# getting values in LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query through which I populate grid. Here is the query,

```
var query = from r in DbContext.Groups
           select 
             new 
               {
                 r.Id, r.Name, r.Description, r.UpdatedBy, r.UpdatedDate, 
                 GroupType =DbContext.ProductTypes.Where(p=>p.Id ==  
                                           r.ProductTypes_Id).Select(t=>t.Name)
               };
```

So, the problem is that the value of grouptype which is extracted from another table is not displaying the value. It is displaying the type(System.Common....). Can you please help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Try

`GroupType =DbContext.ProductTypes.Where(p=>p.Id == r.ProductTypes_Id).Select(t=>new { name = t.Name})`

Or

`GroupType =DbContext.ProductTypes.Where(p=>p.Id == r.ProductTypes_Id).FirstOrDefault().Name`

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the sequence rather than the item.  If you know you're only going to get back one value, use the `.Single` operator:

```
 GroupType =DbContext.ProductTypes.Where(p=>p.Id ==  
                           r.ProductTypes_Id).Select(t=>t.Name).Single()
```

Notice the appending of `.Single()` at the end.

(The reason it was showing the type name is because it was just showing the default `.ToString()` method of the `.Select` operator implementation class.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting

`DbContext.ProductTypes.Where(p=>p.Id == r.ProductTypes_Id).Select(t=>t.Name)`

to return a single value?  Right now it looks like it's assigning a linq anonymous type list, rather than a single value.

If you want a single value, use First, or FirstOrDefault if you can either gaurantee (or not gaurantee) a value returned.

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
.Select(t=>t.Name)
```

is an

```
IEnumerable<ProductType>
```

So you have a collection instead of a single value.

For example, change your query to this:

```
var query = from r in DbContext.Groups
       select 
         new 
           {
             r.Id, r.Name, r.Description, r.UpdatedBy, r.UpdatedDate, 
             GroupType =DbContext.ProductTypes.Single(p=>p.Id ==  
                                       r.ProductTypes_Id).Name
           };
```

However, this code contains dangerous things and I would recommend to add additional checks (for example, this code will throw an exception if the product type is not found, etc.) and, ideally, move this code to the Repository or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple join operation

```
from r in DbContext.Groups join p in DbContext.ProductTypes on r.ProductTypes_Id equals p.Id
select new { Id = r.Id, Name = r.Name, Description = r.Description, UpdatedBy = r.UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate = r.UpdatedDate, GroupType = p.Name };
```